# Why is a application called "java" always open on my OS X 10.9.2 even when I force quit it?

Tags: macos, java

Whenever I turn my computer on I have this application open called "java." No matter what I do I can't exit it. When I try force quitting it, it's called "bin." Images below show what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us your Activity monitor, and 30 lines of the console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Apple< System preferences< Users and groups< there is two tabs here Password & login items< select login items and remove the app from the list>

all the apps & folder added to this section will auto-open when you start up your computer.